# When submitting my contact form, I'm getting "No arguments Provided"

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I submit the form, I get the statement "No arguments Provide!" however, I have a second website running the same exact form and it completely works. The php file is from the Bootstrap Agency template. Here is the code

HTML

```
<div class="span9"> 

        <form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php">
            <p class="contact-name">
                <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="name" />
            </p>

            <p class="contact-email">
                <input id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" />
            </p>

             <p class="contact-phone">
                <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" value="" name="phone" />
            </p>
            <p class="contact-message">
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="Your Message" name="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea>
            </p>
            <p class="contact-submit">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="special" /></li>
        <li><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></li>
            </p>

            <div id="response">

            </div>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 // Check for empty fields
 if(empty($_POST['name'])       ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{
echo "No arguments Provided!";
return false;
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
 $to = 'yourname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
 $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
 $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
 $headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";    
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 return true;           
?>
```

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Comment: The default method when sending in a form is GET.

Comment: You may want to pinpoint the exact cause of error message by splitting the combined `if` statement into several atomic checks, like `if(empty($_POST['name'])) { echo "empty name"; return false; } elseif(empty($_POST['email'])) { echo "empty email"; return false; }`, etc.

Comment: By the way, regarding @jeroen comment, you may use `$_REQUEST['name']` to support both GET and POST methods.

Comment: I still get this now...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/username/public_html/contact.php on line 9

Comment: I'll give your idea a shot @AntonSamsonov. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @AntonSamsonov. It works. I just had to play around with it a bit more. I appreciate it.

Comment: @MeharBanga Could you please share with us your working solution? My bootstrap form stopped working a month ago and I still can't figure out what the cause is.

Comment: @Maleka I posted the answer since I can't add it to this comment. Go take a look :) I believe that's the right one since it's been a while since I touched the contact section to my website.

Answer (score 1):

After digging around for the file, I believe this is the one that works. Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['subject'])     ||
   empty($_POST['message']))    
   /*
   !filter_var($_['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }
    */

    if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
     echo "Please enter your name."; return false; 
     } 
     elseif(empty($_POST['email'])) {
      echo "Please enter your email."; return false; 
      }

     if(empty($_POST['message'])) {
     echo "Please enter your message."; return false; 
     } 
     elseif(empty($_POST['subject'])) {
     echo "Statement if there is an error"; return false;
     }


$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'youname@yourdomain.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $subject";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `method="post"` in your form.

```
<form id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Oh, okay. let me give it a try. Thank you

Comment: This is what I get...

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in /home/username/public_html/contact.php on line 9

Answer (score 0):

The default method when sending in a form is GET.

So you need:

```
<form method='post' id="contact-form" class="contact-form" action="contact.php">
```

Comment: Ah, yes. Thank you